# "message":"The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!","code":500

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman

I have modal, there is a form inside the modal, after filling out the fields, I try to console the data.

I can see that all the data is correct. But the problem is in inserting.

This is my code in inserting of data :

```js
    let data = {
      "blockDates": blockdates,
      "location": location,
      "photos": cardphotos,
      "videos": cardvideos,
      "unit": unit,
      "title": title,
      "catalogId": catalogId,
      "categoryId": categoryId,
      "subcategoryId": subcategoryId,
      "countryId": countryId,
      "provinceId": provinceId,
      "localityIds": localityIds,
      "contentOptions": contentOptions,
      "themeIds": themeIds,
      "why": why,
      "description": description,
      "cancellationPolicy": cancellationPolicy,
      "displayPrice": displayPrice,
      "displayDiscounted": displayDiscounted,
      "displayMaxPax": displayMaxPax
    };

    console.log(data);

    let content = ajax("api/unitContents", JSON.stringify(data), "POST");
    //insert
    // let contentId = null;
    content = content.done(e => {
      console.log(content);
    }).fail(e => {
      console.log(content);
    });
```

this is my global ajax function for api

```
  ajax = (action, data, method) => {
return $.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: `myAPI/${action}`,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${gon.global.currentUser.access_token}`);
  },
  data: data,
  async: !1,
  cache: false,
  error: function (e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
    console.log("Error occured");
  }
});};
```

what are the possible cause of that error?

Comment: Check your request in network tab of browser.

Comment: add dataType: 'json' argument in your $.ajax

Comment: right click in browser -> inspect -> network -> you will see your POST request

Comment: Do you have any documentation on the server api? This is server side error. Normally you would not post an `id` to the server, as this can usually be generated on the backend, but this api seems to be expecting an id. Look at the server api documentation to see what it is expecting.

Comment: same error sir, I add it already

Comment: Definetly your server side code expecting id parameter from request.